# Driver for TP-Link Archer T2U for Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, tp-link

Just realized the TP-Link Archer T2U (ID 148f:761a) I just bought does not plug and play on Kubuntu 20.04

Exact product is https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/adapter/archer-t2u/

The box specifically says linux support is for kernel 2.6-3.16 while Kubuntu 20.04 is far advanced with 5.4.x

Is there some sort of solution that can be applied to make this dongle work on this old machine which currently does not have internet access so `sudo apt-get ...` is less comfortable. if I could only download a thingy/driver and put it on a thumb-drive and plug that thumb-drive into the kubuntu 20 machine and install that thingy/driver and things would work, that would be awesome.

Comment: You can get internet access using your phone connected to USB.

Comment: @mikewhatever 10x! I'll let you know soon. need to work out temporary wired connection. Though these are not the exact devices, there's a slight difference. mine is T2U, while the other is T2UH